# How to specify folder to run .net core tests in AzureDevOps?

Tags: testing, .net-core, azure-devops

**Q:** How to run test for only csproj under certain top-level folder in AzureDevOps?

I have tried every version of this setup I can think of but I just can´t get the test task in AzureDevOps to just find and run/test the projects found in a particular folder.

When this runs it tries to run test on every .csproj in the solution and **not just under the Working Directory**.

**what am I doing wrong?**

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Can you try the Path to project(s): `src/Mp6/Testing/UnitTests/*.csproj` ?

Answer (score 0):

just use *. csproj? that should only look in the current folder.